# OneHotEncoder : __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I'm having this error with onehotencoder where thecategorical_features attribute is missing, I'm using google colab.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
X = star.iloc[:,:6].values
y = star.iloc[:,-1].values
X[:,5] = le.fit_transform(X[:,5])
y[:] = le.fit_transform(y[:])

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [5])
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-93f73a1a04ad> in <module>()
----> 1 ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [5])
      2 X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

Comment: first you should check documentation [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) - it doesn't accept `categorical_features`. Why do you use it?

Answer (score 7):

In documentation for [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) there is no `'categorical_features'`

Older documentation (0.20) for [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) shows that `'categorical_features'` will be removed in 0.22  (and `sklearn` latest version has number 0.22.1) and you have to use [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).

But I don't know how to use it. But maybe examples in [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#column-transformer) can help to use it.

---

**EDIT:**

**Sklearn 0.20**

```
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.20
```

Code

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

print('--- data ---')
X = [
    ['Male',   1],
    ['Female', 3],
    ['Female', 2]
]
X = np.array(X)
print(X)

print('--- LabelEncoder ---')
le = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = le.fit_transform(X[:,0])
print(X)

print('--- OneHotEncoder ---')
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
print(X)
```

Result:

```
0.20.0
--- data ---
[['Male' '1']
 ['Female' '3']
 ['Female' '2']]
--- LabelEncoder ---
[['1' '1']
 ['0' '3']
 ['0' '2']]
--- OneHotEncoder ---
[[0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 3.]
 [1. 0. 2.]]
```

**Sklearn 0.22**

```
pip install -U scikit-learn==0.22
```

Code:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import numpy as np

print('--- data ---')
X = [
    ['Male',   1],
    ['Female', 3],
    ['Female', 2]
]
X = np.array(X)
print(X)

print('--- LabelEncoder ---')
le = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = le.fit_transform(X[:,0])
print(X)

print('--- OneHotEncoder ---')
ct = ColumnTransformer([('my_ohe', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X) #.toarray()
print(X)
```

Result:

```
0.22.2.post1
--- data ---
[['Male' '1']
 ['Female' '3']
 ['Female' '2']]
--- LabelEncoder ---
[['1' '1']
 ['0' '3']
 ['0' '2']]
--- OneHotEncoder ---
[['0.0' '1.0' '1']
 ['1.0' '0.0' '3']
 ['1.0' '0.0' '2']]
```

---

In 0.22 it works even without `LabelEncoder` but 0.20 needs `LabelEncoder`

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import numpy as np

print('--- data ---')
X = [
    ['Male',   1],
    ['Female', 3],
    ['Female', 2]
]
X = np.array(X)
print(X)

print('--- OneHotEncoder ---')
ct = ColumnTransformer([('my_ohe', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = ct.fit_transform(X) #.toarray()
print(X)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the old documentation link, I hadn't seen that and this solved a mystery for me haha. +1!

Comment: Actually I read the doc but doesn't understand much. I'm not getting how to implement this with new onhotencoder.

Comment: [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/46185/83937) seems iteresting. Probably if you use `[5]` instead of `[0]` then you should have your code

Comment: I used answer from previous comment and tested code on 0.20 and 0.22